# An integral problem with Sin and Cos

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a difficulty in calculating the following integral with *Mathematica*:

$$
\int^{\pi}_{0}\rm d\theta_1\frac{ \sin^2\theta_1[2(2-\cos\theta_1\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta\sin\theta_1)^2]}{[(2-\cos\theta_1\cos\theta)^2-(\sin\theta\sin\theta_1)^2]^{5/2}},
$$
where $ \pi>\theta>0 $.

Here is the code:

```
Integrate[Sin[th1]^2*(2*(2 - Cos[th]*Cos[th1])^2 + (Sin[th]*Sin[th1])^2)/((2 - Cos[th]*Cos[th1])^2 - (Sin[th]*Sin[th1])^2)^(5/2), {th1, 0, Pi}]
```

Comment: `Rubi\`Int` can evaluate analytically the indefinite integral with respect to $ \theta_1 $, involved with `EllipticE`.

Answer (score 1):

If numerical solution is sufficient:

```
int[th_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[Sin[th1]^2*(2*(2 - Cos[th]*Cos[th1])^2 +(Sin[th]*Sin[th1])^2)/((2 - Cos[th]*Cos[th1])^2 - (Sin[th]*Sin[th1])^2)^(5/2)
, {th1, 0, Pi}]

Plot[int[th], {th, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, numerical solution can be obtained. However, I think there is analytical solution, because when I use "nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  a1 + a2*Sin[x] + a3*Sin[x]^2 + a8/(1 + a9^2*Sin[x]), {a1, a2, a3, 
   a8, a9}, x]" to fit the numerical solution, the fitted curve is almost 100% same as the numerical curve as you plotted. So I better try to find this analytical solution.

Comment: @Qin-TaoSong Usually the Weierstrass substitution `th1->2 ArcTan[u1]` helps for solving this kind of integral

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Making use of

```
f[x_?NumericQ] =  NIntegrate[ Sin[th1]^2*(2*(2 - Cos[x]*Cos[th1])^2 + (Sin[x]*
     Sin[th1])^2)/((2 - Cos[x]*Cos[th1])^2 - (Sin[x]*Sin[th1])^2)^(5/2), {th1, 0, Pi}]
```

,one obtains

```
f[Pi/4]
```

> 0.676581

and

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the assignment be delayed? as in, `:=` instead of `=`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, numerical solution can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I could come up with is

```
((Sqrt[2]*
  Sqrt[5 + Cos[2*\[Theta]] + 4*I*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]]])/(9*(7 - 
    Cos[2*\[Theta]])))*(2*(3 - 2*I*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])*
 EllipticK[-((I*8*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])/(5 + Cos[2*\[Theta]] - 
       I*4*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]]))] - 
    I*(7 - Cos[2*\[Theta]])*
 EllipticE[
  1 - (I*8*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])/(5 + Cos[2*\[Theta]] + 
      I*4*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])]) - ((Sqrt[2]*
  Sqrt[5 + Cos[2*\[Theta]] - 4*Sqrt[3]*I*Sin[\[Theta]]])/(9*(7 - 
    Cos[2*\[Theta]])))*
 (8*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]]*
 EllipticK[
  1 - (I*8*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])/(5 + Cos[2*\[Theta]] + 
      I*4*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])] - 
I*(7 - Cos[2*\[Theta]])*
 EllipticE[
  1 + (I*8*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])/(5 + Cos[2*\[Theta]] - 
      I*4*Sqrt[3]*Sin[\[Theta]])])
```

I have no idea how to treat the complex moduli further...

Comment: You did this by hand, or by *Mathematica*?

Comment: @MichaelE2 using Mathematica and giving some help with simplification

Comment: Can you show what you did?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It was quite involved: used Ulrich Neumann's substitution to calculate the antiderivative, then (the hard part) find the upper limit at u1->Infinity using Series[antiderivative,{u1,Infinity,0}] and then helped Mathematica simplifying a v_e_r_y large expression

Comment: I guess what I'm trying hint in my second comment is that the answer seems incomplete as is. Unless all one is interested is the result.  But the output does not help me learn how to use *Mathematica*.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I found this open question by the OP and deemed it interesting enough to try a solution. But you learn things only by doing, the strategy for this problem is given in my comment above. The interesting part (for me at least) was the simplification of the enormous expression, which could only be done using a lot of steps that are not made by Mathematica's automatic procedures.